# How to create a list of multiple object types and preserve methods/properties?

Tags: vb.net, list, class, types

I have a program that de-serializes stuff from an xml file and does all kinds of fancy things with it. I have 2 arrays in the XML file, one called `variables` and one called `lookupTables`. I also have 2 classes, `variable` and `lookupTable`. Both of those classes inherit from a class called `definition`. `definition` is inherit only and has one method that must be inherited, `evaluate`. Here is the code:

Definition

```
Public MustInherit Class Definition

            Public Sub New()
            End Sub

            <XmlAttribute("name")> _
            Public Property name As String

            Public MustOverride Function evaluate(variables As Dictionary(Of String, Double)) As Double

        End Class
```

Variable

```
<XmlRoot("variable")> _
        Public Class Variable
            Inherits Definition

            <XmlAttribute("value")> _
            Public Property value As String

            Public Overrides Function evaluate(variables As Dictionary(Of String, Double)) As Double
                Dim calculator As CalculationEngine = New CalculationEngine()

                Return calculator.Calculate(value, variables)

            End Function
        End Class
```

LookupTable

```
<XmlRoot("lookupTable")> _
        Public Class LookupTable
            Inherits Definition

            Public Sub New()
            End Sub

            <XmlElement("data")> _
            Public Property data As Integer()()

            Public Overrides Function evaluate(variables As Dictionary(Of String, Double)) As Double
                Return True
            End Function
        End Class
```

My question is (hopefully) very simple. How can I create a list of `Defintion`s (so a list containing both `Variables` and `LookupTables`) without loosing their individual methods and properties. All I will need to use this list for is calling `evaluate`.

I thought I could just create a `List(Of Definition)` since both `Variable` and `LookupTable` are guaranteed to implement `evaluate()` but as I read, it seems that typecasting both of the lists would strip them of their own innards and keep onluy what is common with `Definition`. What can I do here?

Comment: While you cast an object to Definition, you loose access to the LookupTables/Variables type but you can always cast them back at any time to access them as their children type as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both your objects inherit from definition, you could create a list of **Definition** items then when you need to access specific methods, you cast them to their proper type using directCast to their specific type. To determine the type, you can use

If you had multiple variables types not inheriting from the same base, you could create a list of objects and apply the same idea.

```
'List of definition item
    Private _List As New List(Of Definition)

    'When you want to use specific method, you can cast items back to their types.
    For Each Item As Definition In _List
        Select Case Item.GetType
            Case GetType(LookupTables)
                Dim Table As LookupTables = DirectCast(Item, LookupTables)
                Table.msg() 'Method in my LookupTables class only.
            Case GetType(Variables)
                Dim Variable As Variables = DirectCast(Item, Variables)
                Variable.WriteToConsole() 'Method found in Variables class only.
        End Select
    Next
```

As for casting,
you can cast your LookupType to definition and vice-versa to use their respective methods as needed.

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer was to use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: This answer completely ignores OP's question.